# Use File Watcher in IntelliJ to run Makefile

Tags: go, intellij-idea, makefile, file-watcher

I would like to run a Makefile in IntelliJ whenever a source file changes. Therefore I installed the File Watcher plugin and added a new File Watcher for Go files. In the Watcher Settings I added `make` as the Program and `test` for the Arguments.

When I now change a `.go` file, I get the following error message:

```
make test
make: *** No rule to make target `test'.  Stop.

Process finished with exit code 2
```

so I assume that the file watcher works in general but is somehow runs the make command in the wrong directory.

When I run `make test` in a terminal from the root of my project, everything works as expected and I get:

```
Formatting all packages...
Code analysis with go vet...
Execute test with ginkgo...
[1490735873] Cmd Suite - 1/1 specs • SUCCESS! 120.183µs PASS
[1490735873] Test Helpers Suite - 4/4 specs •••• SUCCESS! 125.046µs PASS
[1490735873] Models Suite - 5/5 specs ••••• SUCCESS! 453.456µs PASS
[1490735873] Services Suite - 16/16 specs •••••••••••••••• SUCCESS! 3.035275ms PASS

Ginkgo ran 4 suites in 855.886243ms
Test Suite Passed
```

What am I doing wrong - or am I missing the point of using file watchers in IntelliJ?

Answer (score 4):

Solution was that I had to specify the *Working Directory* in *Other Options*. When I set this to `$ContentRoot$`, everything works as expected.

[image]

Comment: Good to know, hadn't thought of adding this type of trigger (I only have a `goimports` one configured).